# Setup.py error when installing dlib on Windows 10 [PYTHON]

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition, opencv, dlib

Whenever I try to install dlib using pip install dlib or pip3 install dlib, I get the following error message [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7t1i.png)

I have already downloaded cmake and cv2, and I have also added cmake bin to the environment variables, I am not sure what else I could do to get this working. My main point downloading dlib is to be able to use the face_recognition library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the article on the https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10/

1. Install `CMake` from its official [website](https://cmake.org/download/) and make sure choose the right version according to your system configuration.
2. While installing `CMake` select `Add CMake to the system PATH` to avoid any error in the next steps.
3. Install the [c++ compiler](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) of the visual studio code community version.
4. Install `cmake` library `pip install cmake`.
5. Install `dlib` library `pip install dlib`.

Comment: I was able to install cmake properly this time (using the msi installer and following the website instructions) but I'm still getting the same error when trying to install dlib, any other ideas?

Comment: Have you added it to path?

Comment: Yes, I just double checked it and it is there

Comment: Try this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

if you use windows recomended use conda and run anaconda prompt as admin.
next do below code
1.`conda remove -c conda-forge dlib`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge dlib`

this is work for me